# How to clear a listbox value when another listbox value selected

Tags: javascript

I have created a depending on radio button click listbox will display now if user click a one radio button listbox will display and again user select other option but its not clear a previous value of listbox how to clear it by javascript????

```
<script language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript">
        function fun(s)
        {

             if(s==B)
            {
                  document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='none';
                  document.getElementById("subgroup").style.display='';
                  document.getElementById("itemname").style.display='none';

              }

             if(s==C)
            {
                 document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='none';
                 document.getElementById("subgroup").style.display='none';
                 document.getElementById("itemname").style.display='';


              }


        </script>
```

[Here is the example which i have tried JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/LUY3J/)

Comment: y it cant be clear another selection is selected?????

Answer (score 1):

This is my idea(not tested). Give every your listbox a class name like `class='lst'`. After that when you click on a radio button just use:

```
  `document.getElementsByClassName('lst').style.display = 'none';`
```

and show current listbox.

```
`document.getElementsByClassName('currentListboxID').style.display = 'block';`
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LUY3J/3/)

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question, I have just edited.

Comment: I come back @jagan. Please try demo

Comment: thanks for u r effort but my requirement is if user select top of row like Main Group and then user select Country or city or state etc in second row  so they are two listbox.but u have choosen only one...u can see the above link which i had tried.. is must be select two option??

Comment: sir ...for example now am selecting a main group and country its display some value in table now again i can go with state and maingroup at the time its not shown value for state ...it showing a value of country only...so only approach a method is clear...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
var listBox = document.getElementById("listboxID");
listBox.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/PvrAe/  i have tried but its not work look at the link....please update my code its useful to learn from u???

Comment: yes by radio button it be hide/show the list box but if i select depend on radio button other to clear????

Answer (score 1):

I think show/hide method is not good for programming.

I dont know whether it is useful or not but this might be helpful to you.

You can make it dynamic like

```
var mainGroup = ["aa","bb","cc"];
var subGourp = ["dd","ee","ff"];
var itemName = ["gg","ee","ff"];

var Country = ["jj","hh","ii"];
var Zone = ["kk","ll","mm"];

if(s == A)
{
    var i=0;
    var str = "";
    for(i=0;i<mainGroup.length;i++)
    {
        str += "<option value='" + (i+1) + "'>" + mainGroup[i] + "</option>";

    }
    document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='';
    document.getElementById("maingroup").innerHTML = str;
}
else if(s == B)
{
    var i=0;
    var str = "";
    for(i=0;i<subGourp.length;i++)
    {
         str += "<option value='" + (i+1) + "'>" + subGourp[i] + "</option>";

    }
    document.getElementById("maingroup").style.display='';
    document.getElementById("maingroup").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: client requirement  i dono which is the better way i had searched a web i found this concept alone ...if u have any other approach kindly  share some idea.....

Comment: using the array and use only two dropdowns and fill that with array is the better way to manage rather than create it and make it show hide.

Comment: dropdown will be only two. one for upper radio buttons and another is for second rows radio buttons. Thats it. manipulate using javascript mantioned in above example. its easy

Comment: actually the list box value are from databases after that only i have to customize by it name or id so only i have done this way???

Comment: If you got the value from database then it is the best way because then you have array from database. Otherwise you can manage it also with static array like i mentioned in post.

Comment: k thanks for information...i will follow and update a here of my status

Comment: Hey jagan try this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/LUY3J/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/LUY3J/4/)

Comment: thanks  for u r effort its useful for me i had learn from  u ..now consider the maingroup value its from databases  so now how can i declare array[] for that...like wise for all listbox value ???am beginner of javascript...let u can explain?? in detail if it from databases how to do that.this way.by its name or id...

Comment: First of all what technology have you used for database and what is your platform. and if this post is useful for you then plz Up vote it and mark it as answer.